# Html.ActionLink Action Straggler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

I have a nav menu with links structured like so:

```
<div class="childLinkGroup">
    <div class="headerLink">@Html.ActionLink("Engine Products", null, "EngineProducts", null, null)</div>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Perkins Engines", "PerkinsEngines", "EngineProducts", null, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Isuzu Engines", "IsuzuEngines", "EngineProducts", null, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("FPT PowerTrain", "FPTPowerTrain", "EngineProducts", null, null)</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Mitsubishi Engines", "MitsubishiEngines", "EngineProducts", null, null)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And in the controller class:

```
// GET: /EngineProducts/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(ModelData);
}

//
// GET: /EngineProducts/PerkinsEngines
public ActionResult PerkinsEngines()
{
    ModelData.MenuCategories.Where(x => x.Action == "PerkinsEngines").FirstOrDefault().Active = true;

    return View("Perkins Engines", ModelData);
}
```

These all work fine when accessed from the homepage.

If you're already on a child page like `/EngineProducts/IsuzuEngines` and try to access a different parent level link like `/TransmissionProducts` the `IsuzuEngines` is left on the link resulting in a page that can't be found.

Desired url: /TransmissionProducts

Actual url: /TransmissionProducts/IsuzuEngines

There's a bunch of overrides for `Html.ActionLink` and while I looked though them I don't see a different set of params that looks better.

Comment: Child actions suppose to return partial views. Do you return complete view ?

Comment: In the controller? Let me post some more snippets

Comment: How are your parent links being constructed?  Sounds like a route value is being inherited from a previous request; MVC has this behavior.

Comment: Basically just a bunch of ActionLinks. Check the first link inside my html snippet. Do you have any links I could read up on about this routing behavior you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your parent links are constructed like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Engine Products", null, "EngineProducts", null, null)
```

The previous request value for `action` will be used because you are providing `null` when constructing the link.  You should explicitly specify the action that will be used when a request is made for a parent link.

Comment: Hm, so to get to the default "Index" action I should pass "Index" as the action?

Comment: @AndrewWalters Yes, I believe that should do it.